# How count the time spent on each page in pageview in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a pageview in my home page.. Every page is showing some data(i.e. quote) from list of DataModel..

Here is my code

**homepage.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rdx_test/data_model.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<DataModel> data = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    data.add(DataModel("We are what our thoughts have made us; so take care about what you think. Words are secondary. Thoughts live; they travel far. ~ Swami Vivekananda", 0));
    data.add(DataModel("First they ignore you, then they laugh at you, then they fight you, then you win. ~ Mahatma Gandhi", 0));
    data.add(DataModel("I slept and dreamt that life was joy. I awoke and saw that life was service. I acted and behold, service was joy. ~ Rabindranath Tagore", 0));
    data.add(DataModel("It is no measure of health to be well adjusted to a profoundly sick society. ~ Jiddu Krishnamurti", 0));
    data.add(DataModel("When the flower blooms, the bees come uninvited. ~ Ramakrishna", 0));
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return SinglePage(data: data[index].data);
          }
        ),
      ),
    );

  }

 
}
_pageChanged(int index){
  print("PAGE CHANGED TO : $index");
}

class SinglePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;
  const SinglePage({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SinglePage> createState() => _SinglePageState();
}

class _SinglePageState extends State<SinglePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text(widget.data));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**data_model.dart**

```
class DataModel{
  String data;
  int timeSpent;

  DataModel(this.data, this.timeSpent);
}
```

Now, I want to calculate the time spent on each page. i.e. **how much time is spent by the user on a page?**

Again **if a user swipes back to a page** then the time spent counter will be started again and added with time spent data.

How to do this in **efficient** way ?

Thanking in advance..

**EDIT**

I want to store the life time in their respected data model object.. i.e. timeSpent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing dateTime on initState and dispose method is the best way I can think of to measure lifetime of the widget.

This is the wrapper widget

```dart
class LifeSpanCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  const LifeSpanCounter({
    super.key,
    required this.lifeSpan,
    required this.child,
  });

  final Function(Duration spent) lifeSpan;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<LifeSpanCounter> createState() => _LifeSpanCounterState();
}

class _LifeSpanCounterState extends State<LifeSpanCounter> {
  late DateTime initTime;
  @override
  void initState() {
    initTime = DateTime.now();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.lifeSpan(DateTime.now().difference(initTime));
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.child;
}
```

And wrap the widget you like to get lifespan

```dart
LifeSpanCounter(
  lifeSpan: (spent) {
    data[index] = data[index]
        .copyWith(timeSpent: data[index].timeSpent + spent);
  },
  child:YouurWidget
```

For your database I like to modify the coding style

```dart
class DataModel {
  final int id;
  final String data;
  final Duration timeSpent;
  DataModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.data,
    this.timeSpent = Duration.zero,
  });

  DataModel copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? data,
    Duration? timeSpent,
  }) {
    return DataModel(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      data: data ?? this.data,
      timeSpent: timeSpent ?? this.timeSpent,
    );
  }
}
```

test snippet

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<DataModel> data = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    data.add(DataModel(
      id: 0,
      data:
          "We are what our thoughts have made us; so take care about what you think. Words are secondary. Thoughts live; they travel far. ~ Swami Vivekananda",
    ));
    data.add(DataModel(
      id: 1,
      data:
          "First they ignore you, then they laugh at you, then they fight you, then you win. ~ Mahatma Gandhi",
    ));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return LifeSpanCounter(
                lifeSpan: (spent) {
                  data[index] = data[index]
                      .copyWith(timeSpent: data[index].timeSpent + spent);
                },
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("s ${data[index].timeSpent.inSeconds}"),
                    SinglePage(data: data[index].data),
                  ],
                ));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```